# Chrome browser terminatting automatically

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

Chrome version 54.0.2840.99m and 
Chrome driver 2.25

When I try to find an element from a web page using below code.
    require 'selenium-webdriver'
    require 'rubygems'

```
driver=Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.manage.window.maximize
driver.navigate.to "myURL"
test1 = driver.find_element(:id, "email")
```

chrome has initiated, redirected to gievn URL and then automatically closed. Where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Chrome will be closed at the end of the script. If you want to keep it open, you need to set the `detach` option to `true`:

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {'detach' => true})
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps
```

Comment: Now, required page is opened & closed then an empty chrome browser is popped up

Comment: Sounds like you just put these 2 lines at the bottom of your existing script. These lines are meant to replace your existing `driver=Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome` - ie the `detach` option is something you need to specify when opening the browser.